# Assing variable to arrays inside function that gets 2 arrays and returns match & unmatch from each

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, loops

Interface -

```
interface I {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  size?: string;
}
```

Empty arrays -

```
let firstArrayMatches: I[] = [];
let firstArrayUnmatches: I[] = [];

let secondArrayMatches: I[] = [];
let secondArrayUnmatches: I[] = [];
```

First array -

```
const firstArray: I[] = [
  {
    name: 'daniel',
    age: 30
  },
  {
    name: 'tamir',
    age: 30
  }
]
```

Second array -

```
const secondArray: I[] = [
  {
    name: 'daniel',
    age: 30,
    size: 'm'
  },
  {
    name: 'ariel',
    age: 28,
    size: 'm'
  }
]
```

Mapping the `secondArray` return `string[]` -

```
const secondArrayIndexes = secondArray.map(({ name, age }) => name  + '/' + age);
```

loop through the `firstArray`, If match push the object into `firstArrayMatches` & push `...secondArray.splice(match, 1)` into `secondArrayMatches`, else push object into `firstArrayUnmatches`, And assing the second array into `secondArrayUnmatches`.

```
for (const o of firstArray) {
  const match = secondArrayIndexes.indexOf(o.name + '/' + o.age);

  if (match >= 0) {
    firstArrayMatches.push(o);
    secondArrayMatches.push(...secondArray.splice(match, 1));
  } else {
    firstArrayUnmatches.push(o);
  }
}
secondArrayUnmatches = secondArray;
```

Output -

```
console.log('first match: '+ JSON.stringify(firstArrayMatches))
console.log('first unmatch: '+ JSON.stringify(firstArrayUnmatches))

console.log('second match: '+ JSON.stringify(secondArrayMatches))
console.log('second unmatch: '+ JSON.stringify(secondArrayUnmatches))
```

first match: `[{"name":"daniel","age":30}]`
first unmatch: `[{"name":"tamir","age":30}]` 
second match: `[{"name":"daniel","age":30,"size":"m"}]`
second unmatch: `[{"name":"ariel","age":28,"size":"m"}]`

Wanted output -

first match: `[{"name":"daniel","age":30,"size":"m"}]`
first unmatch: `[{"name":"tamir","age":30}]` 
second match: `[{"name":"daniel","age":30,"size":"m"}]`
second unmatch: `[{"name":"ariel","age":28,"size":"m"}]`

The function should assign properties from the second array to the first if there is a match.

Answer (score 0):

Array mutations is a bad idea most of the time. Just filter your elements out :

```
function compare(i1: I, i2: I) {
    return i1.name === i2.name && i1.age === i1.age
}

const firstArrayMatches = firstArray.map((p1) => secondArray
    .find((p2) => compare(p1, p2)))
    .filter((p) => p)
const firstArrayUnMatches = firstArray.filter((p1) => !secondArray.some((p2) => compare(p1, p2)))


const secondArrayMatches = secondArray.filter((p1) => firstArray.some((p2) => compare(p1, p2)))
const secondArrayUnMatches = secondArray.filter((p1) => !firstArray.some((p2) => compare(p1, p2)))
```

Or as a reduce :

```
firstArray.reduce((acc: { match: I[], unmatch: I[] }, p1: I) => {
    const p2 = secondArray.find((p2) => compare(p1, p2)) 
    p2 ? acc.match.push(p2) : acc.unmatch.push(p1);
    return acc;
}, { match: [], unmatch: [] })
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJLIN4FgBQz-IhwC2EAXMgM5hSgDmA3LgcnHeYQK7EBG0TeApWAAvCAH4K1WiEa4AvrlwIA9iGrIYwKNQCCUKHACeFVAG0AusgC8yM8wLZBLfEVIUA5ABM4IYBAAbDwAaBxdWdgoAZgAGMOR5UOdMeJY3Dg8wEm0Q1II2Dlj4xRwLJRxVdTAqCEqvfUMTNEsbO3incNcSDJ8-QNzklgLomKTOqlEM4g9iscc8rvdkDzhafrnw4eQAJgAODZdhMU9p4twynFwYThAEMGA1ZFViAAdViAAKYABGU2DkYDbUwAShSySgEDAnCgIAB3wAdOkbNZbIDEd1kAAyTFw+EFZGohEFBTlSoaLQ6MANYwAWTgYAQAAsIJRWhS9AZjPDiHAXh8Pi9vqDrAA+Gp1alGeLwrQgLz8l7bYVi55vCEC77-RXAnXSrQBSBQBXK5AvYHKNTk7QcxoAVRAdIZzNZtnZVM5RhlwAN0AVQpsYoAhJRamp6h74ZQVKQFUqA09o2rPoKtUrdZcM2TqiGJR7HUyWa0c2HJV6fUaNSa3aWozGBXHRQnXu8NamdeaKpbs6G5ZL7fnnUWe+HGmXDX6TYHqxHa596ybVS2U6a0x3SV3NNbqq6t6WIV5OEh+YgEBQMMgeU7TJZ-jdL0zr1ZEqbfmgTR0CFmV0Pc6PZfL53jRd1WXbUOxYRVkHEVgEAQbl6SZeEXk4ShGUAigT3hO8EMZJCULQwVgQEFgIShGEYIQARn3Pe9GQoG9kGwq87CfNdM0tFQAggeEAhUOgPmnRoBxZf5BOMfscJZIiLXUTjuN4-i3SIoA)

Comment: Do you understand that your answer has nothing to do with my question?
You just did what I did in another way and that's not what I've asked